# addEventListener on clicked li - prevent this if a link is clicked that is inside the li

Tags: javascript

I have an addEventListener on a clicked list item. I want to prevent this addEventListener if a link is clicked that is inside the list item.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xea1eku/ - so in this example. I want to prevent the toggle action if `this` is a clicked link. How may I do this?

```
<div class="faq">
    <ul>

        <li>
            asdasdasdasdaa
            <span class="answer">
                <a href="http://google.com">clickme</a> jdiajdoi asjdoiaj sdoiaj odsjaso djaosdj oaisjdo.
            </span>
        </li>

        <li>
            asdasd
            <span class="answer">
               sadoia hdoas jdiajdoi asjdoiaj sdoiaj odsjaso djaosdj oaisjdo
            </span>
        </li>


        <li>
            asdasdasdasd
            <span class="answer">
               sadoia hdoas jdiajdoi asjdoiaj sdoiaj odsjaso djaosdj oaisjdo
            </span>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>

if (document.getElementsByClassName('faq').length > 0) {

    var faqItems = document.querySelectorAll('.faq li');
    for (var i = 0; i < faqItems.length; i++) {

        faqItems[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Is using jQuery an option?

Comment: So many ways this could be done. Really need more details about what you are trying to accomplish.If you ONLY want to ignore clicks on A elements, then could check explicitly for this scenario by inspecting the target of the event object. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/8xea1eku/1/

Comment: you could look if "this" is a <li> inside the function?

Comment: @loddn `this` will always be an `<li>` inside the function because the event listener is attached to the `<li>` element specifically. He needs to check the target of the event. The event he is catching has bubbled up from the `<A>`.

Comment: sry, the target of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event object to see what was clicked.

```
    faqItems[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName==="A") return;
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    });
```

Comment: This won't work for `button`, or other elements that may have interaction tied to them. But this directly answers the OPs question as he phrased it.